# Shadow making image bend

Tags: html, css

Please refer the image.
As seen in the image i want to vertically bend the image by giving it shadow.
tried a lot but could not get it.

```
<html>
<head>
   <title></title>
   <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

   <!-- jQuery library -->
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
   <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <style type="text/css">
 .main{
    background-image: url('http://www.detaildesignonline.com/contentimages/sky1285264350.jpg');
    min-height: 600px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: rgba(4,58,106,1);
    border-bottom-width: 10px;  
}
.heading{
    font-weight: 900;
    color:#004B81;
}
.more{
    color:rgba(159,67,66,1);
}
.leftForm{
    background-color: rgba(224,237,222,1);
    height: 350px; 
}
.rightForm{
    background-color: rgba(253,253,253,0.7);
    height: 350px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="height:10px; background-color:orange"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div><img src="http://tollfreecustomercarenumber.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/ICICI-bank.jpg" height="100px" width="250px"></div>
            <div class=""></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    </div>  
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10 main">
            <div class="col-sm-1">

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-11">
                <h3 class="heading">We've got all your Forex needs covered!</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas vitae mi et leo tristique <br>tincidunt ac nec est. Aenean volutpat mauris vitae erat ultricies varius.</p>
                <p><b class="more">What's more? </b><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas <br>vitae mi et leo tristique tincidunt ac nec est.</b></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-5 leftForm">
                    <form role="form">
                    <br>
                    <h3 style="color:rgba(159,67,66,1); margin-top:0px">Sign In</h3>
                      <div class="form-group col-xs-8">
                        E-Mail ID
                        <input type="email" style="border: 2px solid orange;" class="form-control" id="email">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-xs-8">
                        Password
                        <input type="password" style="border: 2px solid orange;" class="form-control" id="pwd">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-12">
                      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="background-color:rgba(159,67,66,1); color:white" value="LOG IN"></input><br>
                      <small style="color:rgba(159,67,66,1)"><u><a  style="color:rgba(159,67,66,1)" href="#">Forgot Password?</a></u></small>
                      </div>    
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-5 rightForm">
                    <form role="form">
                    <br>
                    <h3 style="margin-top:0px">Sign Up</h3>
                      <div class="form-group col-xs-8">
                        *E-Mail ID
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-xs-8">
                        *Password
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-xs-8">
                        *Re-enter Password
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
                      </div>
                      <div class=" col-xs-12">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="background-color:rgba(102,102,102,1); color:white">SIGN UP</button>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                <!-- <p style="height:10px; bottom:0px; background-color:rgba(4,58,106,1)"></p> -->
                </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <br>
            <div style="line-height:23px"><p style="color:rgba(102,102,102,1); font-size:12px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas vitae mi et leo tristique tincidunt ac nec est. Aenean volutpat mauris vitae erat ultricies varius. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas vitae mi et leo tristique tincidunt ac nec est. Aenean volutpat mauris vitae erat ultricies varius. Aenean volutpat mauris vitae erat ultricies varius. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p></div>
            <div class=""></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    </div>
```

Please refer the image i want to bend it vertically through shadow. Please explain me the logic also.[image: image vetically bend through shadow]

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [perspective property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_perspective.asp) on the box-shadow.

That's an example of CSS to append:

```
.main:after{
    content: '';
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    bottom:0px;
    width:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-47%;
    height:30px;
    box-shadow: 0 16px 30px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(0deg) rotateX(45deg);
    -moz-transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(0deg) rotateX(45deg);
    -ms-transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(0deg) rotateX(45deg);
    -o-transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(0deg) rotateX(45deg);
    transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(0deg) rotateX(45deg);
    margin-left:-62%;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(300px) rotateY(-40deg) rotateX(50deg);
    -moz-transform: perspective(300px) rotateY(-40deg) rotateX(50deg);
    transform: perspective(300px) rotateY(-40deg) rotateX(50deg);
}
```

I think it's your job to adapt it.

Comment: This makes a perspective shadow but at the bottom of the `main` container. You need to adapt it on both the sides and resize the shadow.

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
 width:400px;
 height:300px;
 background:#fff;
 margin:40px auto;
}
img { 
  display:block;
  width:400px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.effect{ 
  position: relative;
  transform:rotate(90deg);
  top:-280px;
  left:-50px;
  z-index:-1
}
.effect:before
{
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width:300px;
  background: #777;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
.effect2{ 
  position: relative;
  transform:rotate(90deg) scaleY(-1);;
  top:-620px;
  left:50px;
  z-index:-1;
  
}
.effect2:before
{
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width:300px;
  background: #777;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://politic365.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2012/02/laptop_beach_black_man-e1329324187523.jpg">
<div class="effect"></div>
<div class="effect2"></div>
```

Comment: Please include an explanation and not just a code dump in your answers

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the *rotate* value of the *transform property* in *CSS*.

Here is a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sleonard947/zgrbz6tz/5/) for your review.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("p:nth-of-type(2)").css("font-weight", "bold");
});
```

```css
html {
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
}
h1 {
  color: #003F87;
}
a {
  color: #800000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
label {
  display: block;
  curser: pointer;
}
#button {
  background-color: #939393;
  color: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #003F87;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
#button:hover,
#button:active {
  background-color: #003F87;
  border-color: #939393;
  color: #fff;
}
.container {
  width: 920px;
  height: 250px;
  background: white;
}
.shadow {
  position: absolute;
}
.shadow:before,
.shadow:after {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 0;
  left: 15px;
  width: 200px;
  top: 12px;
  background: #939393;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -15px 7px 15px #939393;
  -moz-box-shadow: -15px 7px 15px #939393;
  box-shadow: -15px 7px 15px #939393;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
.shadow:after {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 15px 7px 15px #939393;
  -moz-box-shadow: 15px 7px 15px #939393;
  box-shadow: 15px 7px 15px #939393;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
  transform: rotate(3deg);
  right: 15px;
  left: auto;
}
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 900px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 650px;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: url('http://www.pd4pic.com/images/business-man-man-tie-suit-business-silhouette-1.png'), url('http://www.detaildesignonline.com/contentimages/sky1285264350.jpg');
  background-size: 30% 90%, 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom right, center;
}
.content {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  height: 500px;
}
.top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
.primary,
.secondary {
  width: 350px;
  display: inline;
  height: 300px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  line-height: 23px;
}
.primary {
  float: left;
  background-color: rgba(11, 181, 255, .3);
}
.secondary {
  float: right;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container shadow"></div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="top">
      <h1>
        We've got all your Forex needs covered!
      </h1>
      <p>
        Presenting Forex@Click, an easy to use and secure portal that takes care of all
        <br>your Forex requirements, whether its tranferring of funds, buying of a Travel
        <br>Card, Travel Insurace or currency.
      </p>
      <p>
        <a href="#">What's More? </a> Customers having an account in any private or nationalized
        <br>bank are welcomed to enjoy our services.
      </p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <form name="register" method="post" action="/signin" novalidate="">
      <div class="primary">
        <h2>Sign In</h2>
        <div>
          <label for="email">E-Mail Id</label>
          <input name="email" id="email" type="text" required>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="password">Password</label>
          <input name="password" id="signin-password" type="text" required>
        </div>
        <div>
          <br>
          <button id="button">LOGIN</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <form name="register" method="post" action="/signup" novalidate="">
      <div class="secondary">
        <h2>Sign Up</h2>
        <div>
          <label for="signup-email">*E-Mail Id</label>
          <input name="signup-email" id="signup-email" type="text" required>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="signup-password">*Password</label>
          <input name="signup-password" id="signup-password" type="text" required>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="signup-password-confirm">*Re-Enter Password</label>
          <input name="signup-password-confirm" id="signup-password-confirm" type="text" required>
        </div>
        <br>
        <button id="button">SIGN UP</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```